# Is SQL Express 2008 subject to the same 5 connection limitation as file sharing on Windows XP?

Tags: windows-xp, sql-server-2008

File sharing on Windows XP has a 5 client limitation.  Our solution uses both file sharing and SQL Express.

The way I see it, we have 2 options here:

-Reload the machine that they want to use as a server with Windows Server, or;

-Supply them with a dedicated NAS server, and keep their server machine on Windows XP

The second option is the preferred one, for reasons I'm not going to go into.  I just need to confirm that the 5 client limitation applies to the file sharing only.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at this [feature comparison chart](http://www.microsoft.com/sqlserver/2008/en/us/editions.aspx), it seems there is no limit on the number of connections. The big differences seem to be CPU, RAM, and database size limitations.

### EDIT

While there is nothing in the SQL Server Express docs about Windows connection limits, I did find this MS KB article, [Inbound connections limit in Windows XP](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/314882). It appears that Windows XP Professional has a 10-connection limit, and Windows XP Home has a 5-connection limit.

> **Note** For Windows XP Professional, the
>   maximum number of other computers that
>   are permitted to simultaneously
>   connect over the network is ten. This
>   limit includes all transports and
>   resource sharing protocols combined.
>   For Windows XP Home Edition, the
>   maximum number of other computers that
>   are permitted to simultaneously
>   connect over the network is five. This
>   limit is the number of simultaneous
>   sessions from other computers the
>   system is permitted to host. This
>   limit does not apply to the use of
>   administrative tools that attach from
>   a remote computer.

Comment: What I'm worried about is whether the OS would restrict more than 5 connections.  I'm quite confident that SQL would allow it, but will Windows?

Comment: I don't see anything in the documentation to indicate that Windows will limit the SQL Express connections. Can you setup a test machine and try it out?

Answer (score 1):

If you run it on XP, then it is limited. I don't know if the limit is *enforced*, but if you pass it it you are still in violation of XP's license agreement.  If you have multiple users connecting to your server, you really should run it on a server operating system.  Windows Server 2008 R2 is current, but SQL Server Express should work down to Server 2003.

Answer (score 0):

I know it's been "answered" for a while but for the reference of others who may happen upon this question, there is no and has never been a CONNECTION limit to MSDE/SQL Express.

There is a workload governer in MSDE 1.0 and MSDE 2000 that would cause things to slow down if more than 5 (and subsequently 8 in 2000) operations were occurring at once, but that was dropped in SQL Express 2005 and later.

For reference, see:
[Link](https://web.archive.org/web/20160219215720/http://blogs.msdn.com:80/b/euanga/archive/2006/03/09/545576.aspx)